# LESS:: css rules inside media queries dont append values on looping

Tags: css, less, media-queries

I want a mixin to input multiple background image urls to generate 1x and 2x background image rules.

**Definition::**

```
.multiple-bg(...) {
    @len: length(@arguments);
    @i: 1;

    .generate(@list, @i) when (@i <= @len) {
        @src : extract(@list, @i);
        background-image+: ~'url("@{src}")';

        @filename  : ~`/(.*)\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)/.exec(@{src})[1]`;
        @extension : ~`/(.*)\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)/.exec(@{src})[2]`;

        @media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
            background-image+: ~`"url(@{filename}@2x.@{extension})"`;
        }
        .generate(@list, @i + 1);
    }
    .generate(@arguments, @i);
}
```

**Usage::**

```
selector {
  .multiple-bg("link1.jpg", "l1nk2.jpg", "link3.jpg", "l1nk4.jpg");
}
```

**Output::**

```
selector {
  background-image: url("link1.jpg"), url("l1nk2.jpg"), url("link3.jpg"), url("l1nk4.jpg");
}
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  selector {
    background-image: url(link1@2x.jpg);
  }
}
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  selector {
    background-image: url(l1nk2@2x.jpg);
  }
}
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  selector {
    background-image: url(link3@2x.jpg);
  }
}
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  selector {
    background-image: url(l1nk4@2x.jpg);
  }
}
```

The output is as expected for the 1x rule but for the 2x rule which involves a media query it doesnt combine the urls but creates seperate media query for all.

i have used the "+" operator mentioned in the less language features to do this. http://lesscss.org/features/#merge-feature-space

can anyone suggest a solution, any approach is fine.

Comment: `+` cannot merge rules defined in different media blocks, it's simply impossible (nor Less may safely merge similar media blocks automatically, see [#950](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/950) for more details).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep rulesets/properties in the same media block you need to keep the loop that generates them in that very same media block, e.g.:

```
selector {
    .multiple-bg("link1.jpg", "l1nk2.jpg", "link3.jpg", "l1nk4.jpg");
}

.multiple-bg(@list...) {
    .-();
    @media only screen 
        and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
            .-("@2x");
    }

    .-(@suffix: "", @i: length(@list)) when (@i > 0) {
        .-(@suffix, @i - 1);
        @src: replace(extract(@list, @i), "\.", "@{suffix}.");
        background-image+: url(@src);
    }
}
```

Comment: perfect solution. i was very close, made me think